# Concatenar dois arquivos que possuem mesmo nome NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

basicamente eu preciso concatenar dois arquivos (o conteúdo) que possuem o mesmo nome e possuem formato MDX, em um novo arquivo. Atualmente estou utilizando o [concat-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-files) mas estou fazendo isso manualmente, ou seja, arquivo por arquivo. Os arquivos estão localizados em pastas diferentes, exemplo:

Arquivo 1: `node_modules/meumodulo/docs/doc1.md`

Arquivo 2: `docs/half/doc1.md`

Então, com esse módulo `concat-files`, eu gero um terceiro arquivo que é o produto dos arquivos 1 e 2 e ele vai pra outra pasta.

Minha ideia é deixar isso de forma automática, para ele varrer a pasta `node_modules/meumodulo/docs/` e `docs/half/` e concatenar os arquivos que possuem o mesmo nome, mas estou sem ideia de como fazer isso. Se puderem dar uma força! Obrigado!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Esta é uma solução que não utiliza o `concat-files`.

Para esta implementação estou utilizando exclusivamente o módulo [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), disponibilizado no nodejs.

Conforme a sua necessidade, você deseja "concatenar" (unir) dois arquivos que possuem o mesmo nome, porém estão em diretórios diferentes, então inicialmente eu declarei duas variáveis `patha` e `pathb` que são os diretórios que desejamos "procurar" por arquivos com o mesmo nome.

Também declarei uma variável `pathdestino` que é o diretório em que serão armazenados os arquivos que são o resultado da concatenação dos arquivos.

Para auxiliar nesta tarefa utilizei a função [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options) que serve para listar os nomes dos arquivos que pertecem a um diretório. O sufixo Sync no nome do método (`readFileSync`) significa que estou utilizando a implementação síncrona deste método. Esta função vai retornar uma lista que contém os nomes dos arquivos.

Com a função [`writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) ela vai escrever em um certo diretório o conteúdo do arquivo (aqui é o que deseja fazer que é concatenar o conteúdo dos arquivos que possuem o mesmo nome). Esta função vai apenas criar um novo arquivo no sistema de arquivos do sistema operacional. Você deve passar apenas o nome do diretório que deseja criar.

Com a função [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) serve apenas para ler o conteúdo do arquivo.

Nesta solução eu criei uma função auxiliar `lerConteudoDiretorio` e `escreverConteudoArquivo` que manipula as funções descritas acima caso aconteça algum erro.

No foreach e que eu comparo os nomes dos arquivos que estão no diretório `a` com os nomes dos arquivos que estão no diretório `b` caso eles sejam iguais então eu concateno o seu conteúdo separados por uma quebra de linha.

Esta lógica está descrita neste trecho de código:

```
if (filea === fileb) {
        const a = fs.readFileSync(patha + `/${filea}`).toString();
        const b = fs.readFileSync(pathb + `/${fileb}`).toString();
        escreverConteudoArquivo(pathdestino + `${filea}`, `${a}\n${b}\n`)
}
```

A solução completa é a seguinte:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const patha = '/caminho/diretorio/a';
const pathb = '/caminho/diretorio/b';
const pathdestino = '/caminho/diretorio/destino/';

const lerConteudoDiretorio = (diretorio) => {
    try {
        return fs.readdirSync(diretorio);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Não foi possível ler o conteúdo do diretório '${diretorio}'. Detalhe: ${err}`)
    }
};

const escreverConteudoArquivo = (diretoriodestino, conteudo) => {
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(diretoriodestino, conteudo);
        console.log(`Arquivo ${diretoriodestino} escrito com sucesso`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Não foi possível escrever o conteúdo do arquivo no diretório '${diretorio}'. Detalhe: ${err}`)
    }
}

const filesa = lerConteudoDiretorio(patha);
const filesb = lerConteudoDiretorio(pathb);


filesa.forEach(function (filea) {
    filesb.forEach(function (fileb) {
        if (filea === fileb) { //se os nomes dos arquivos são iguais
            const a = fs.readFileSync(patha + `/${filea}`).toString();
            const b = fs.readFileSync(pathb + `/${fileb}`).toString();
            escreverConteudoArquivo(pathdestino + `${filea}`, `${a}\n${b}\n`)
        }
    });
});
```

Para executar com sucesso estou supondo que o conteúdo dos arquivos são texto.

### Explicação do algoritmo

supondo que temos a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
.
+-- _diretorioa
|   +-- a.txt
|   +-- b.txt
|   +-- c.txt
+-- _diretoriob
    +-- b.txt
    +-- c.txt
    +-- d.txt
```

Então após a execução do script o resultado será:

```
.
+-- _diretoriodestino
    +-- b.txt
    +-- c.txt
```

Que são os arquivos que possuem o mesmo nome.

---

Em relação ao conteúdo dos arquivos eles serão gerados da seguinte forma:

***diretorioa/b.txt***

```
hello
```

***diretoriob/b.txt***

```
world
```

***diretoriodestino/b.txt***

```
hello
world
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!